# Wrong message showing in Laravel validation for multidimensional array

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have this validation rules and i appended some custom messages for those validations.

```
 $this->validate($request, [
            'name'=>'required',
            'departments.*.name'=>'required',
            'departments.*.sections.*.name'=>'required',
        ],[
            'name.required'=>'The division name field is required.',
            'departments.*.name.required'=>'The department name field is required.',
            'departments.*.sections.*.name.required'=>'The section name field is required.',
        ]);
```

Screenshot of my view:

[image]

Here you can see, the empty section input field showing error message

> "The department name field is required."

But it should be show

> "The section name field is required."

What am i missing?

***Note:***  i am printing the first index of all fields error messages

Comment: may i know what version of laravel you are using

Comment: i am using laravel 5.7

Comment: share your blade file

Comment: i am using vue component for this. all of my scripts are placed in vue component

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its replacing the error messages from `departments.*.sections.*.name.required`

You should add child dimension errors before parent fields

**try to use this:**

```
 $this->validate($request, [
            'name'=>'required',
            'departments.*.name'=>'required',
            'departments.*.sections.*.name'=>'required',
        ],[
            'name.required'=>'The division name field is required.',
            'departments.*.sections.*.name.required'=>'The section name field is required.',
            'departments.*.name.required'=>'The department name field is required.',
        ]);
```

Comment: awesome. its worked. but i don't know what was the problem on it. can you please explain more on it ?

Comment: you can understand on your own by getting the validation error on dd(); example: $validatedData = $request->validate([ your validation rules ]); and then dd($validatedData); thanks

Comment: it seems you have not made any changes in question's code you just copy it and paste it as it is so how can you solved the above problem, please explain

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta Kamrul has already explained see `You should add child dimension errors before parent fields`

Comment: check the last line and second last line. 2nd dimensional validation (sections.*) should be placed before 1st dimension validation error. If not then the validation message replaced with "The department name field is required."